# Am i over using modular pattern here?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn modular pattern in javascript right now i am refactoring my previous side project a tasks app from jquery to plain js. I wish to know if what i'm doing here is right because i feel like i am over using the pattern here

```
(function(){
    const nameSetBtn = document.querySelector('#name-setting-btn');
    const nameSetModalParent = document.querySelector('.modal-parent');
    const nameSetModalMain = document.querySelector('.modal');
    const nameSetModalInput = document.querySelector('#name-setting-input');
    const mainInterface = document.querySelector('.main-interface');
    const createSetBtn = document.querySelector('#create-set-btn');

    const NameSetting = (function(){
        function animateModal(){
            nameSetModalMain.style.width = '30%';
            nameSetModalMain.style.opacity = '0';
            nameSetModalParent.style.opacity = '0';
            delayHide = setTimeout(function(){
                nameSetModalParent.style.display = 'none';
            }, 500)
            MainUI.setUI();
        }
        return {
            validate : function(){
            const nameValue = nameSetModalInput.value;
            const nameLength = nameValue.length;
            if(nameValue === '' || nameLength < 5){
                    alert("You're name should be at least 5 characters to 10 characters long");
                } else if(nameLength > 10) {
                    alert("You're name must only be at least 10 characters long");
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem('username', nameValue);
                    console.log(this)
                    return animateModal();
                }
            }
        };
    })();

    const MainUI = (function(){
        function show() {
            const greeting = document.querySelector('#greet');
            greeting.innerText = 'Welcome!, ' + localStorage.getItem('username');
            mainInterface.style.display = 'block';
        }
        return {
            checkUser : function(){
                if(localStorage.getItem('username')){
                    nameSetModalParent.style.display = 'none';
                    this.setUI();
                } 
            },
            setUI : function(){
                const currentDate = new Date();
                const dateStringHolder = document.querySelector('#date-string');
                dateStringHolder.innerText = currentDate.toDateString();
                const dateTimeHolder = document.querySelector('#date-time');
                const tickTime = setInterval(function () {
                        dateTimeHolder.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
                }, 1000)

                return show();
            }
        }
    })();

// The tasks model not done yet
    function SetModel(setName){
        this.setName = setName;
        this.tasks = [];
    }


    SetModel.prototype.nameOfSet = function(){
        console.log(this.setName);
    }

    createSetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const newset = new SetModel('Name this set');

    })



    MainUI.checkUser();
    nameSetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            NameSetting.validate();
    })

})();
```